# How can I increase the size of a gomap popup window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want my goMap-driven popup windows to be large enough that they don't need scroll bars. How can I increase the height and width of the popup window?

My jQuery and HTML is:

```
$("#map").goMap({ 
     address: 'Seaside, California',
     maptype: 'ROADMAP',
     zoom: 11
}); 

$.goMap.createMarker({
     address: '2555 Garden Road, Monterey, California',
     title: '2555 Garden Road, Monterey',
     html: '<img src="KelvinsPhotoCollage.jpg" height="240px" width="360px" alt="2555 Garden Road property"></br><p class="blueBold">Existing Building</p><p class="values"> 19,322 sf</p></br><p class="blueBold">Acreage</p><p class="values">3</p></br><p class="blueBold">Parking</p><p class="values">100 spaces</p></br><p class="blueBold">Asking Price</p><p class="values">$3.5 million</p></br><p class="blueBold">Suggested Offer</p><p class="values">$2.8 million</p></br><p class="blueBold">Estimated Improvement Costs</p><p class="values">$800,000</p></br><p class="blueBold">Total</p><p class="values">$3.6 million</p></br><p class="blueBold">Planning Approval Schedule</p><p class="values">1.5 years</p></br><p class="blueBold">Comments</p><p class="values">Price not official</p>'
 });
```

...and it takes up too much space.

CSS is:

```
.blueBold {
    color: navy;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
.values {
    display: inline-block;
    color: purple;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Consolas, Candara, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use **[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)** in order to have more control over the popup window **[goMap](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/)**.

**[Have a look here for this](http://www.femgeek.co.uk/popup-google-map-using-fancybox/)**

Does this helps you?